# How call button click in User control referenced in another project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I have two projects in my solution, one WPF User control library named UserControls and second WPF Application named ShopApplication.

In UserControls I have created simple Class named Product with some property (string Name example) and User controler designed by Caliburn Micro MVVM pattern, ... my View is ProductListView.xaml in Views folder, and viewmodel is named ProductListViewModel.cs in ViewModels folder. ShopApplication is MVVM designed always.

My view looks like this:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="UserControls.Views.ProductListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600"               
         >
      <Grid>
      <TextBox Name="SearchingText"/>
      <Button x:Name="Search" Content="Search"    
                   cal:Message.Attach="[Click]=[Search()]"/>        
      </Grid>
      </UserControl>
```

And in my ViewModel I Have method named Search().

When I include my user control into the ShopApplication (In application Window view) this way:

```
    <ContentControl DataContext="AreBoughtControl" >
        <userControls:ProductListView/>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl DataContext="WillNeedToBuyControl" >       
         <userControls:ProductListView/>
    </ContentControl>
```

Always when I click on Search button the Exception is unhandled (No target found for method Search.). But when I define Search method in ViewModel of application window it is OK and method is invoked.

But I do not want invoke method in ShopApplication, I need to Invoke method in UserControl which has List of products and search name in this list.

How can I do that ? Thx for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out why exception is thrown on button click. Alternatively  you can Implement ICommand for Button click rather than directly Binding the Search Method to the Button click. This will solver your problem easily. Since Your following MVVM it easy to implement ICommand.

You can refer the below links for details about ICommand

http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.in/2013/04/icommand-interface-and-relaycommand.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

Comment: Thak you very much, you really help me, the first link is exactly what I need, +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

2 things come to mind :

1) Your not describing Attach in the proper manner for a button , try

```
 <Button  cal:Message.Attach="Search" />
```

2) Why do you place your UserControls 
   as Contents inside ContentControl , this is not the use of a ContentControl , 
   UserControls derive from ContentControls and they describe content .

```
    <userControls:ProductListView DataContext="AreBoughtControl"/>        
    <userControls:ProductListView DataContext="WillNeedToBuyControl"/>
```

Further more I'm assuming you have 2 properties in your Window's DataContext called AreBoughtControl and 
WillNeedToBuyControl and they are both of the Type you intended , check and see if this is so..

Comment: I Answer my Questions, because the message was too long,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have two properties od type ObservableCollection();
but your advice is not right, ...Search method is still not found, only if I place Search method into the ShopApplication Viewmodel
this is my ProductListViewModel:

```
     namespace UserControls.ViewModels
     {
        public class ProductListViewModel : 
                         Screen,INotifyCollectionChanged
        {
             public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { 
              get; set; }
             public 
             ObservableCollection<Product>FilteredProduct{get; 
              set; }

       public ProductListViewModel()
       {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        FilteredProducts = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
       }

       public void Search()
       {
          //search in collection
       }
```

and my Application ViewModel:

```
    namespace ShopApplication.ViewModels
    {
        public class ShopViewModel : 
           Screen,INotifyCollectionChanged
        {
          private Screen _areBoughtControl;
          private Screen _willNeedToBuycontrol;

    public Screen AreBoughtControl
    {
        get { return _areBoughtControl; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _areBoughtControl)) return;
            _areBoughtControl = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AreBoughtControl);
        }
    }

    public Screen WillNeedToBuycontrol
    {
        get { return _willNeedToBuycontrol; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _willNeedToBuycontrol)) return;
            _willNeedToBuycontrol = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WillNeedToBuycontrol);
        }
    }

    public ShopViewModel()
    {
        AreBoughtControl = new ProductListViewModel();
        WillNeedToBuycontrol = new ProductListViewModel();
    }

    //public void Search()
    //{

    //}
   }
  }
```

I want call onClick method in ProductListViewModel , not in ShopApplicationViewModel

Comment: This should work have you checked the output window for Binding errors ?

Comment: How can I do that, because I can t show error, I can see only output :
WindowsBase.pdb not loaded , ... No target found for method Search.